# Complex separators in read.csv

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to work on a very large dataset in R. It's currently a saved as a CSV and I'm using read.csv to import it in. Unfortunately, one of the fields is Address, which naturally contains commas and R is obviously reading these as separators. One positive, all of the commas within the addresses are followed by spaces.

So here's the question. Is there anyway of telling read.csv that ", " is not a separator but "," is?

If not, is there anyway I can import a csv into R as one long string to then do a find and replace? Or, last resort, could you point me in the direction of a decent text editor that I can get away with installing on my work laptop?

Thanks, James

Comment: Is it really a long file (e.g. >= hundreds of MB) or can it easily fit in memory ?

Comment: There are no quotes around your addresses? Yell at the person who created such a messy file. I'd suggest to use sed or awk to substitute all `,` that are not followed by a space with something else (e.g., `;`).

Comment: You could try something like `read.table(text=gsub(",(?=\\S)", "\t", readLines("file.csv"), perl = TRUE), header = TRUE, sep = "\t")`

Comment: It's a 2GB file so no chance of opening it in excel.

Comment: And yeah, no quotes. I will yell. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give them a go

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt would be to get the file recreated using either quotes or a `|` separator.

If that weren't an option, I would then try to use `readLines` and `gsub`, 
assuming I can read all of those character strings into memory.

```
library(dplyr)

File <- 
  paste("Name,Address,Occupation,Hair Color",
        "Mary,123 Lamb St, Ruralsville, KY,Shepherd,Blonde",
        "Jim,17 Elm St., Urban Center, TN,Butler,Brown",
        sep = "\n")


write(File, tmp)

DF <- readLines(tmp) %>%
  gsub(", ", "_;_", .) %>%
  textConnection() %>%
  read.csv() %>%
  mutate(Address = gsub("_;_", ", ", Address))

unlink(tmp)
```

If the file were too large to read into memory, I would likely attempt to write a loop
that reads 100,000 lines at a time, performs the above code on each segment, and 
writes it to a new CSV.  The new CSV will be properly quoted from R and should read in
fairly well.

(I haven't tried to write this loop yet.  I"m hoping for your sake it doesn't come to that)